# How to design SQL tables capturing parent child like a blog post and its sub posts

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

The use case is to store a list of blog posts where each post can have multiple child posts belonging to different types.

The approach that I have in mind is - All posts go into this master table. A single post can have multiple parent posts. It is for this reason, I thought having a separate table to hold the relation would be better.

**tblPost**

| postId | title | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | parent post title | test test |
| 2 | child post title | test test |
| 3 | second child post title | test test |

**tblPostRelations**

| id | postId | parentPostId | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | NULL | Type1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | Type2 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 | Type3 |

So for any given post, I will query this table to find out if it is a child and render it as a subsection in the UI.

The design looks simple, but not sure if the approach is alright. Any ideas on improving/tuning/pointing obvious mistakes ?

Comment: @TimothyAlexisVass One table seems actually correct - posts are posts as such, so would it be easy to advance design to multi-level posts.

Comment: Timothy is suggesting you put parentPostid & Type into tblPost and drop tblPostRelations altogether.

Comment: Ok a single post can have multiple parent posts. I will edit my question to bake this condition in. Also, a type like you said is to categorize based on subject.

Comment: I can't see point of having separate table for post relations - unless you plan to use more links than parent-child relation. Include parentpostid into main posts table and you are almost done :)

Comment: How can single post have multiple parents?

Comment: It is not exactly a parent as such - more like an association. A post is related to several other posts which in my business case is deemed a parent.

Comment: Are parent and association same or different things? If (almost) same, then your structure is OK. If they are very different, then I would think about maintaining parent-child structure in main table and associations in relation table. Goes into 'opinion based' area :)

Comment: @Arvo what do you mean by "same or different things"? A post can have multiple child posts and can also have multiple parents. Although, having multiple parents sounds odd - but thats how the vendor passes on the data

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't the type be in the upper table?

Not sure, as your table structure suggests that the type determines the type of relation while your description (at least as I understand it) says it is the type of the post...

Under the condition that the type should be a row of the upper table:

1. You could scrap the first line in the table "tblPostRelations", it contains no information besides the type
2. You could create a composite key for that table (containing "postId", "parentPostId") since that should be a unique combination if I interpreted your description right

The tables would then look sth. like this:

**tblPost**

| **postId** | title | description | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | parent title | test test | Type1 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

**tblPostRelations**

| **postId** | **parentPostId** |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |
| ... | ... |